# /etc/vfstab in Solaris 11

Tags: mount, solaris

I would like to mount a folder from the remote server `10.12.13.2`.

When I type: `mount -F nfs 10.12.13.2:/username /remote/username`, the folder username gets mounted in the directory `/remote/username`.

Now I would like to make an entry in the `/etc/vfstab`, but without **mount at boot**.

```
10.12.13.2:/username   -       /remote/username       nfs     -       no      rw
```

Now, how can I mount the directory?

When I type mount `/remote/username`, I always get: `mount: mount point cannot be determined`

Comment: double check the vfstab entry. that messages means that he cannot find the entry in the vfstab
Ensure that the /etc/vfstab is properly configured (recommended tabs between fields)

Comment: Does the mountpoint exist? Are you inadvertently including a trailing slash that tab-completion can append? I.e., are you running "mount /remote/username/" instead of "mount /remote/username"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that the `/remote/username` directory exists.  If it doesn't, you'll need to create the empty placeholder directory, and then try your 'mount /remote/username'.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming you didn't disable the default /net automount:

```
ln -s /net/10.12.13.2/username /remote/username
ls -l /remote/username
```

Answer (score 0):

I think on solaris nfs mounts should be placed in /etc/dfs/dfstab. Take it with a grain of salt, a large one at that, as Solaris is not my forte.

Comment: dfstab is for exports.